# Double quotoes around <script> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-tag-manager

Recently I've added a google tag manager script in the head-section of my HTML-file. But after it initialized, i noticed strange quotation marks at the end of my page.
After a little investigation, it turned out, that the gtm-script adds another  tag between my scripts before `</body>` and content of the page with double qutoes around it.
So far i have fixed it with `font-size: 0` on body and by wrapping content in additional `<div>`. 
But maybe somebody knows, how to fix it without such workaround?

My head-section:

```
<head>
  <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
  <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-T12TASN');</script>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>(title)</title>
  <meta content="(description)" name="description">
  <meta content="(og:title)" property="og:title">
  <meta content="(og:description)" property="og:description">
  <meta content="http://address.com/share.png" property="og:image">
  <meta content="summary" name="twitter:card">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <meta content="Webflow" name="generator">
  <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css/webflow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!-- [if lt IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><![endif] -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    !function(o,c){var n=c.documentElement,t=" w-mod-";n.className+=t+"js",("ontouchstart"in o||o.DocumentTouch&&c instanceof DocumentTouch)&&(n.className+=t+"touch")}(window,document);
  </script>
  <link href="//address.net/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
  <link href="https://address.net/icon.svg" rel="apple-touch-icon">
</head>
```

Script with quotation marks:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you please include code of your head-section?

Comment: From what I understand, I think  you can try giving display:none to that div? or else yu can move the script in the head part to a seperate file or move it after the next script part.

Comment: Can you please also attach your tags, which you created in GTM. I am pretty sure one of them is inserting this quotes at the end

Comment: These are probably coming from the conditional tag for support of IE browsers lower than version 9 (for whatever obscure reason that these should still be supported in 2017). I don't see any reason why these would bother you, this is just how these comments are rendered